# Apache - Django - ImportLib do not import module

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, mod-wsgi, centos7

I deploy django-project and i am block to a problem of loading module.

My project work perfectly `MYENVPYTHON/manage.py migrate` or with runserver or just call the wsgi.py file.

But when i will deploy with apache the script i had an error in the error_log file of apache :

```
[THEDATE] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 49174] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[THEDATE] [core:notice] [pid 49611] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[THEDATE] [suexec:notice] [pid 49611] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[THEDATE] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 49611] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[THEDATE] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 49611] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[THEDATE] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 49611] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_wsgi/4.6.4 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[THEDATE] [core:notice] [pid 49611] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP] mod_wsgi (pid=49612): Failed to exec Python script file '/PATHTOMYPARENTPROJECT/MYSITE/MYSITE/wsgi.py'.
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP] mod_wsgi (pid=49612): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/PATHTOMYPARENTPROJECT/MYSITE/MYSITE/wsgi.py'.
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP] Traceback (most recent call last):
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP]   File "/PATHTOMYPARENTPROJECT/MYSITE/MYSITE/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP]   File "/PATHTOMYENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP]   File "/PATHTOMYENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP]   File "/PATHTOMYENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP]     self._setup(name)
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP]   File "/PATHTOMYENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP]   File "/PATHTOMYENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 109, in __init__
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP]   File "/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 49612] [remote MYIP] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MYSITE'
```

I try to identify the problem and add in the `/PATHTOMYENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py` file this line :

```
print(importlib.util.find_spec(self.SETTINGS_MODULE))
```

and i have this error :

```
........

[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 55926] [remote MYIP]   File "/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 109, in __init__
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 55926] [remote MYIP]     print(importlib.util.find_spec(self.SETTINGS_MODULE))
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 55926] [remote MYIP]   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/util.py", line 89, in find_spec
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 55926] [remote MYIP]     parent = __import__(parent_name, fromlist=['__path__'])
[THEDATE] [wsgi:error] [pid 55926] [remote MYIP] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MYSITE'
```

If i call the wsgi.py file with the env python interpreter i have the list of all modules in INSTALLED_APPS list in my settings.py file.

Thanks in advance for your help.

## EDIT 1

The content of my `wsgi.py` file

```
"""
WSGI config for MYSITE project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""
import os
import sys

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "MYSITE.settings")

# sys.path.append('/PATHTOPARENTFOLDER/MYSITE/MYSITE')
sys.path.append('/PATHTOPARENTFOLDER/MYSITE')

# sys.path.append(os.sep.join(os.path.abspath(__file__).split(os.sep)[:-2]))

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

## EDIT 2

For more information, i give here my apache.conf file:
(I have comment lines herited from previous test)

### django.conf

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /PATHTOMYENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

CustomLog logs/mysite-access_log common
ErrorLog logs/mysite-error_log


#<VirtualHost *:80>

    # ServerName www.DNS.com:80
    # WSGIPythonHome /PATHTOMYENV/
    # WSGIPythonPath /PATHTOPARENTFOLDER/MYSITE
    # WSGIDaemonProcess MYSITE python-path=/PATHTOPARENTFOLDER/MYSITE:/PATHTOMYENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages

    WSGIDaemonProcess MYSITE python-home=/PATHTOMYENV python-path=/PATHTOPARENTFOLDER/MYSITE
    WSGIProcessGroup MYSITE

    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptAlias / /PATHTOPARENTFOLDER/MYSITE/MYSITE/wsgi.py
    Alias /static /PATHTOPARENTFOLDER/MYSITE/static
    <Directory /PATHTOPARENTFOLDER/MYSITE/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /PATHTOPARENTFOLDER/MYSITE/MYSITE>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

#</VirtualHost>
```

## EDIT 3

Here the version of tools used :

```
Django (install via pip in my venv)= 2.0.6 
mod_wsgi (install via pip in my venv)= 4.6.4
CentOS = 7.5.1804
Http-Apachectl = 2.4.6-80.el7.centos
Python (in venv) = 3.6.5
```

Here my file tree for the MYSITE and MYENV

```
/PATHTOPARENTFOLDER + ----MYSITE
                    |  + ----MYSITE 
                    |  |  + ----wsgi.py 
                    |  |  + ----settings.py 
                    |  |  + ---- .......
                    |  + ----OTHERAPPS
                    |  + ----manage.py
                    + ----MYENV
```

The `django.conf` file is here `/etc/httpd/conf/django.conf` and he is call by `httpd.conf`

Comment: Can you show us your `wsgi.py` file? There are some tweaks necessary to run the stock `wsgi.py` with `mod_wsgi`.

Comment: edited @FlipperPA.

Comment: `find_spec` appears to be creating an error when added to the `__init__.py` in Django itself - I would remove it. Can you try this line in place of your `sys.path.append` calls? `sys.path.append(os.sep.join(os.path.abspath(__file__).split(os.sep)[:-2]))` It will automagically append the path from the parent of the `wsgi.py` file.

Comment: Move the ``from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application`` to after your changes to ``sys.path``.

Comment: @FlipperPA, thank for your tip. I edited my post. But your tip didn't change the error log :/ If you need more information, please tell me.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, thank for your tip. I edited my post. But your tip didn't change the error log :/ If you need more information, please tell me.

Comment: Just use ``sys.path.append('/mnt/storage_cnr_1/Site_CNR')`` and not what you have adde to try and work it out automatically. The automatic one looks like might be adding the wrong directory. So be explicit to begin with.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton i edited the `wsgi.py` with your tip (if i understood correctly). After a `sudo apachectl restart` and a refresh of the webpage, it was not change the error log in apache.

Comment: Can you update question which what you are currently using.

Comment: Tell me if you have all you wanted in my last edit @GrahamDumpleton.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i finally find the solution...

...and...

... it was a permission problem solved with the help of this tuto https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/how-to-install-django-with-apache-on-centos-7/

with the line `sudo chown -R apache:apache /opt/djangoproject`.
I had made it but just add the group `apache` and not the group AND the user `apache`.